# How to add edittext and checkbox into listview android?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a problem, when edit-text is setted enable as false. I want to set the edit-text enable as true when the user check the check box in list view but it's not working properly

Comment: change the arraylist value and notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: you have to use custom adapter which extends any adapter basic adapter like ArrayAdapter and BAseAdapter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the getView method of the customadapter add these lines:

```
holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(holder.cb.isChecked())
            {
            //enable edit text
         }
          else
        {
        //disable edit text
         }
            }

    });
```

Comment: is this work to check another check-box in one row list-view? i have layout "checkbox(1) edittext checkbox(2)", i want to check checkbox(1) automatically when i check checkbox(2)

Comment: yes it will work and for the setting the checkbox automaticallly set checkbox1.setChecked (true) when you checked second check box